# Android How to focus map on your currently location or marker location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am using Google map, to add multiple marker to it.

But when the map loads, it does not focus on the markers on the map.

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
....


    private void loadMap(){
        Log.d(TAG, "loadMap");

        //Load MAP
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />



    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(doubleLat, doubleLon)).title(name));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Animate `Camera` on that `Marker`

```
LatLng pos=new LatLng(latitude,longitude); 
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(pos, 18.0f));
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `CameraUpdateFactory` to achieve the same, you can do like below :

```
CameraUpdate center=
    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(doubleLat, doubleLon));
CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);

map.moveCamera(center);
map.animateCamera(zoom);
```

You can add this code inside `onMapReady()` callback .